# How to prevent modal appearing on page load while using backdrop:'static'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, popup

I have a dialog box which should appear whenever I click on a checkbox. But **it should not disappear when clicking outside or pressing escape**. so I used backdrop='static' , keyboard='false' in my jquery.
but then this dialog box is appearing whenever I **load or refresh the page**.

```js
$('#storeStatusDialog').modal({
      backdrop: 'static',
      keyboard: false
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="modal fade" id="storeStatusDialog" role="dialog" >
        <div class="modal-dialog armanlast">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <div class="close-icon-wrap">
                        <a class="modal-close-icon" href="#" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h1 class="modal-title1">Deactivate Store</h1>
                    <p class="deactivate-p"></p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" id="noDeactivate" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default cancel-confirm1 btn-approval1" onclick="statusOnAgain()">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" id="yesDeactivate" class="btn btn-default confirm-complete1 btn-approval1"><span style="horizontal-align:middle">Yes</span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please tell me a way to prevent dialog box appearing when page gets loaded.
thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#storeStatusDialog">
    Launch
  </button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="storeStatusDialog" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog armanlast">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <div class="close-icon-wrap">
          <a class="modal-close-icon" href="#" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <h1 class="modal-title1">Deactivate Store</h1>
          <p class="deactivate-p"></p>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" id="noDeactivate" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default cancel-confirm1 btn-approval1" onclick="statusOnAgain()">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" id="yesDeactivate" class="btn btn-default confirm-complete1 btn-approval1"><span style="horizontal-align:middle">Yes</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Js:

```
  $('#storeStatusDialog').modal({
    show: false,
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
  })
```

Snippet:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpEjxK

Comment: Thank You so much dude.. Code is working fine now.... I didn't know it was this much simple..